# Grid content JSON conversion

Tags: servlets, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a grid where user and add new rows as many as they want. After adding all the rows, they click the "Save" button. On Save button click, I want to send all the data entered by the user in JSON format to the server side code (i.e. a servlet in my case)

Below is the model and store definition:

```
 Ext.define('Plant', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        // the 'name' below matches the tag name to read, except 'availDate'
        // which is mapped to the tag 'availability'
        {name: 'common', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'botanical', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'light'},
        {name: 'price', type: 'float'},
        // dates can be automatically converted by specifying dateFormat
        {name: 'availDate', mapping: 'availability', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'm/d/Y'},
        {name: 'indoor', type: 'bool'}
    ]
});


// create the Data Store
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    // destroy the store if the grid is destroyed
    autoDestroy: true,
    model: 'Plant'
});
```

On click of the save button, I am able to get the store like this:

```
{
        text: 'Save',
        handler : function(){
            //Getting the store
            var records = grid.getStore();
            console.log(records.getCount());
            Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: '/CellEditing/CellEditingGridServlet',
                method: 'POST',
                jsonData: {
                    //How to assign the store here such that 
                    //it is send in a JSON format to the server?
                },
                callback: function (options, success, response) {

                }
            });
        }
```

But I don't know like how to convert the store content into JSON and send it in the `jsonData` of the ajax request.

I want the JSON data something like this in the server side:

```
{"plantDetails":
[
{
    "common": Plant1,
    "light": 'shady',
    "price": 25.00,
    "availDate": '05/05/2013',
    "indoor": 'Yes'
}, 
{
    "common": Plant2,
    "light": 'most shady',
    "price": 15.00,
    "availDate": '12/09/2012',
    "indoor": 'No'
},
]
}
```

Please let me know how to achieve this.

Regards,

Comment: you should use a proxy for this. http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax

Comment: Make sure and look up the sync function for the store, makes life much easier once you've got the store properly set up with its ajax proxy.

Comment: the comments really helped a lot, can you please let me know abt the following reason?

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with Neil, the right way to do this is through an editable store outfited with a proxy and a writer. See example here: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/grid/cell-editing.html

Comment: the comments really helped a lot, can you please let me know abt the following reason?

Answer (score 1):

Store

```
writer :
            {
            type : 'json',
            allowSingle : true
            }
```

Experiment with allowSingle as per your use case

In your controller

```
//if you want to set extra params
  yourStore.getProxy().setExtraParam("anyParam",anyValue);
// sync the store
  yourStore.sync({success : function() {
         yourGrid.setLoading(false); 
    .. },
    scope : this // within the scope of the controller
  });
```

You should be creating the model with a new id ( you can ignore it at the server side and use your own key generation , but it lets extjs4 for its internal purposes know that a new record has been created).

creating a model instance

```
var r = Ext.create('yourModel', { id: idGen++, propA : valA , ... });
```

insert to grid

```
store.insert(0,r);
var editPlugin = grid.getPlugin(editPluginId);
editPlugin.startEdit(0,1);
```

Once you receive a response back the id's can be update to their true value.

in the Store

```
reader :
    {
        type : 'json',
        root : 'yourdata',
        successProperty : 'success',
        idProperty : 'id'
    }
```

If you were to use the same grid for handling and editing then you could use the write event or the appropriate event

for more advanced handling in the Store

```
listeners :
    {
        write : function(store,operation, eOpts)
        {
            var insertedData = Ext.decode(operation.response.responseText);
                    .. do something
        }
    }
```

I would recommend using the mvc architecture of Extjs4

Answer (score 0):

This is what I tried and it seems to work:

```
 var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    // destroy the store if the grid is destroyed
    autoDestroy: true,
    model: 'Plant',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/CellEditing/CellEditingGridServlet',
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'plantDetails'
        }
    }

handler : function(){
            grid.getStore().sync();
```

But I am getting an additional parameter in the JSON at the server side:

```
"id": null
```

I don't have this `id` set in my model then where is this coming from? Is there some way to set some values to it rather than having a default null value?

Comment: idProperty is set to id by default and is a required field. you should set this property on your model to the primary key of your record.